# Is it possible to list files in a dir with Azure storages

Tags: django, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage, django-storage

I'm using Django and django-storages[azure] as backend.
But i can't to find out to list dir the files instead I have to use snippets like this:

`block_blob_service.list_blobs(container_name='media', prefix=folderPath)]`

this is not working:

`listdir(absoluteFolderPath)`

In storages/backend/azure_storage.py I found this part:

```
def listdir(self, path=''):
        """
        Return directories and files for a given path.
        Leave the path empty to list the root.
        Order of dirs and files is undefined.
        """
        files = []
        dirs = set()
        for name in self.list_all(path):
            n = name[len(path):]
            if '/' in n:
                dirs.add(n.split('/', 1)[0])
            else:
                files.append(n)
        return list(dirs), files
```

But how can I use it?

regards
Christopher.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you have set [DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#std:setting-DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE) you could access it through [storage](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/files/#storage-objects)

```
from django.core.files.storage import default_storage
dirs = default_storage.listdir(absoluteFolderPath)
```

Answer (score 1):

The API for `listdir` returns a tuple of two lists, the first being the directories (folders) in the given path, the second being the files.

The correct way to unpack this would be to assign two variables during the call.

Examples:

```
from django.core.files.storage import default_storage

# list the contents of the root directory of the storage
directories, files = default_storage.listdir('')

# list the contents of a directory named 'images' inside 'media'
directories, files = default_storage.listdir('media/images')

# now you can iterate through just the files
for filename in files:
    print(filename)
```

I'm using django-storages with S3, but Azure looks to work exactly the same.